# ThreadPoolExecutor.submit() with multiple functions and different arguments

Tags: threadpoolexecutor

Let's take this tuple :

```
    functions = (
     (func1, (arg1, arg2)),
     (func2,   (arg3)),
     (func3, (arg5, arg6, arg7),
     (func4, ()
    )
```

Now I want to use ThreadPoolExecutor.submit() to create a thread for each entry in a loop. How would I do that ?

Nothing I tried worked :-)